# Unable to HotSwap HFS+ Formatted SATA Drives (on a Windows Machine)

Tags: sata, hfs+, hotswapping

I'm having problems getting HFS formatted drives to hotswap on my Windows 7 Machine

- I have 2x [Manhattan SATA drive racks](http://www.manhattan-products.com/en-US/products/6206-sata-drive-rack) installed in my computer
  connected to the GSATA ports on my [Gigabyte EX58-UD3R](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=3265#ov).
- I work with Windows and Mac machines so the majority of my drives are
  formatted HFS and I run [MacDrive](http://www.mediafour.com/products/macdrive) on my windows machine.
- I've recently reinstalled Windows with AHCI enabled so I can hot-swap
  drives using the Manhattan racks.
- The drives are all WD Caviar Greens
- Running Windows 7 x64

With the computer logged in I can connect a NTFS drive (using the racks) and they are detected and mounted within 5 seconds. **But when I connect a HFS formatted drive they dont register at all...** Even when I rescan for hardware changes the drive still doesnt show up.

Further more, if I have booted with the HFS drive connected it does show up in windows, but if I then connect a NTFS drive in the second bay the HFS drive after 10-20 seconds disappears.

I can also connect the HFS drive fine using a USB dock, but this is not ideal.

Any thoughts much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

**I connected the drives to the regular SATA ports on my motherboard** and so far its working much better.

Though sometimes if I have a drive connected, and then I connect another drive the first drive dissapears and I need to scan for hardware changes to bring it back. Better than nothing though!